# =IF(test,mot,"?") How to know what is hidden behind a logical test in an xlsx on Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I Have an xlsx in spreadsheet and there is a cell with an expression `=IF(test,mot,"?")`. I would like to know what is hidden in the logical expression.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

I tried to convert it to a Google Sheet and give a look at the Google scripts but there was nothing.

[Here is a link to the xlsx](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p-urDsPkRyv4ULFTX0XHB4l6i9-nYPXY/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100143345999442003446&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have come across a "named range". A cell, a range of cells, or a formula in a spreadsheet can be called some kind of understandable word and then used in formulas. This is very convenient, since the notation

`= Price * Quantity`

is much clearer than something like `=B64*D64`.

You can read more about named ranges in the article [**Create a named range from selected cells in a worksheet**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-named-range-from-selected-cells-in-a-worksheet-fd8905ed-1130-4cca-9bb0-ad02b7e594fd)

To see what names are in the workbook in Excel - press **Ctrl+F3**

[image: Excel named ranges]

And in Google Sheets, just click this arrow here

[image: Sheets named ranges]

Answer (score 0):

Those are named ranges :) In A59 there's a formula (test), if it's true it returns B59 (mot). If not, it returns "?"

[image]